# Fetch elements from a website which load after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

When I fetch from a website using `fetch`, I need to figure out a way to get an element which loads after 3-4 seconds. How should I attempt to do this? My code currently is

```js
const body = await fetch('websiteurl')
let html = await body.text();

const parser = new DOMParser();
html = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

html.getElementById('pde-ff'); // undefined
```

I can assure this element exists and if I go to the website and use the last line and replace `html` with `document`, it works but I need to wait for website to load. Any ideas?

Comment: how is that element which loads after 3 or 4 second render on the DOM? a http request? a script?

Comment: It renders as a html element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty much your stuff isnt loading at the correct time

so you need to wait for html to open and theres a lot of ways to do this

1. use jquery `$(function() {alert("It's loaded!");});`
2. use vanilla js `window.addEventListener('load', function () {alert("It's loaded!");})`